# NMAP discovery scan reporting host offline, pinging the same host gets ICMP responses

Tags: nmap, icmp, host-discovery

I ran an `nmap -sn` scan on a host, and `nmap` reported the host as down. I then pinged the same host with `ping` and got ICMP responses. I'm confused, because I was sure that `-sn` among other things, did an ICMP `echo` request.

Output from my two commands:

```
~ $ nmap -sn 192.168.1.237 

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-16 09:35 BST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.00 seconds

~ $ ping 192.168.1.237
PING 192.168.1.237 (192.168.1.237) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.237: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=9.82 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.237: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=5.25 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.237: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=2.95 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.237: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=9.10 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.237 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.957/6.785/9.826/2.810 ms
```

Any ideas why NMAP could be confused? I'm running the scan from my Ubuntu 16.04 box, the target is a Windows 10.

Comment: Try `-T2 --scan-delay 1s --reason -n -Pn -sO -p1` or even `-T2 --scan-delay 1s --reason -n -Pn -sP`

Comment: The flags `-T2 --scan-delay 1s --reason -n -Pn -sP` I don't thing do anything of value unless combined with others? It boils down to just `-sP -Pn`.  And `sP` is just the old flag for `-sn`. So it's basically asking for a service scan without a ping or port scan.  So it returns "host is up" on anything ip.  `nmap -s0 -Pn -n 0.0.0.0` returns `Host is up.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to run a ping scan, make sure you are running as `root`.

From [nmap archived docco](https://nmap.org/bennieston-tutorial/):

> When you run an Nmap ping scan as root, the default is to use the ICMP
>   and ACK methods. Non-root users will use the connect() method, which
>   attempts to connect to a machine, waiting for a response, and tearing
>   down the connection as soon as it has been established (similar to the
>   SYN/ACK method for root users, but this one establishes a full TCP
>   connection!)

So you need

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.237
```

Your ping will have the SUID bit set, so that it always runs as root no matter which user you execute it under. This is why it is possible for ping to detect the server, whereas nmap cannot.

Comment: [Current reference](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) says "For unprivileged Unix shell users, the default probes are a SYN packet to ports 80 and 443 using the connect system call."